# Check if an item in a listbox is already present in many other listboxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have about 42 listboxes.  I'm making a schedule using dragdrop and drag enter.

Sample:

```
private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{

    if (listBox1.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");

    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
    }
}
```

Where should I put that error message so that it will not copy that data.

Comment: You forgot C# 5.0 and C# 6.0

Comment: Only 5 tags allowed and he didn't want the one left out to feel lonely.

Comment: hi guys i'm sorry i didn't noticed my tags. Do you have any idea guys about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add in each of the 42 listboxes only those items not yet added.

No error message is needed.

```
 if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)))    
            listBox1.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
```